# How can I extract some data from a array of dict to put in a array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to extract some data from an array of dict but it does not work...

Here is my code :

```
var myarray = [{'country': 'US', 'type': 'eat'}, {'country': 'DE', 'type': 'test'}]

var arr = []
for (var key in myarray){
if (key.hasOwnProperty('country')){
        arr.push(key.country)
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

What I want at the end is this `arr = ['US', 'DE']`

I precise I am using React.js maybe there is a function more efficient to do that ... but I did not found...

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/n3o61bcw/

Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myarray = [{'country': 'US', 'type': 'eat'}, {'country': 'DE', 'type': 'test'}];
const arr = myarray.map(c => c.country);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the iterable `key` of an array is just its index. So you're checking whether `0.hasOwnProperty('country')` e.t.c. which obviously doesn't make sense. You could fix this by doing:

```
if (myarray[key].hasOwnProperty('country')){
        arr.push(myarray[key].country)
    }
}
```

But it makes more sense to reduce the array instead:

```
const arr = myarray.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c.country || []), []);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve isn't related to `React` specifically, It can be done using javascript functionality. On the other hand, you want to return the value of the specific key  of each object inside of `myarray`

You can perform that using `Array.prototype.reduce` method like this

```js
let myArray = [
  {'country': 'US', 'type': 'eat'}, 
  {'country': 'DE', 'type': 'test'}
];

const result = myArray.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  return accumulator.concat(current.country);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

of using `Array.prototype.map` like this

```js
let myArray = [
  {'country': 'US', 'type': 'eat'}, 
  {'country': 'DE', 'type': 'test'}
];

const result = myArray.map(item => {
  return item.country;
});

console.log(result);
```

There many way to achieve the same result